# bootstrap.stage42 like theme for bootstrap 3?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, themes, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have stumbled upon a page, http://bootstrap.stage42.net, which has a really nice theme. Does anyone know where to get a similar theme for bootstrap3?

Please see:
http://bootstrap.stage42.net

TIA
/Søren

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just the normal bootstrap theme, except for the navbar-brand, which actually is a image. To get this sort of bootstrap looks, just link all those files:

```
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<!-- Optional theme -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">

<!-- Latest compiled and minified JavaScript -->
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.3/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

(directly copied from http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/

Comment: Hi, I am not sure if I understand. Aren't you simply pointing to standard bootstrap themes? stage42 has 3D effects on buttons, menus, breadcrumbs etc.

Comment: If you include the optional theme you will get the 3d look-a-like effects ;)